# Change password field text color only when iOS password manager highlights the field yellow

Tags: css, ios, reactjs

I have a React site where the normal text color of my login / signup password fields is white.

When iOS password manager has a password suggestion for the sign up password field, it highlights the field yellow and the white password text is difficult to read.

As far as I can tell, the only way to prevent the yellow highlighting is to change the field type to 'one-time password', or by disabling autofill, both of which break normal password field behavior like password manager intervention, which is not good.

Is there a way to change the font color in the text field selectively, ie only when iOS password manager is taking over the box? Or is there another way to keep the normal white text color for most purposes but to make it more legible when iOS forces the yellow background when managing passwords?

[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nypI9.jpg)

Edit: someone asked for code - this the current field

`<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="current-password" id="password" name="password" required="" type="password" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input css-h4os0j" value="">`

Comment: There is no any code provided inaide this question which is not good. But the answer is something like: look at the classes autoadded by the passowrd manager and rewrote the styling with !important. In your case it should be something like .pass-gen-class { background: white !important }

Comment: Could you add a runnable snippet so we can see what your settings actually do. In particular to understand your color choices. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I don't see how an example is needed here. It's a known fact that ios adds yellow background to autocompleted fields. In op's example, the field has white text and dark background initially, but the autocomplete makes it unreadable. How adding any code will change anything here?

Comment: @Konrad I was interested in the coloring and also the structure used to see if something could be done e.g. with mix blend mode.